# Mobile navigation with sliding dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

i'm trying to create a seperate mobile navigation for a website i'm creating. this is the basic html layout right now

```
    <nav class="mobile-navigation">
    <ul class="header-mobile">
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/index.php"><img src="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$template}/img/logo/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/cart.php?a=view"><span class="icon icon-nav-account"></span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/cart.php?a=view">
                        <span class="icon icon-cart"></span>
                        <span class="notification-amount">{$cartitemcount}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="row">
    <ul class="nav-mobile">
        <li><a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/about.php">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/servicesc.php">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/domains.php">Domains</a></li>
        <li><a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/support.php">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with a simple script to toggle the menu

```
    $('.fa-bars').click(function(evt) {
    $('.nav-mobile').slideToggle('down');
});
```

Now i'm trying to create something where if a list item is chosen, the dropdown is displayed like the images below.

[first list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoaiL.png) -->
[second list with selected item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vtoB.png)

anyone an idea how i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change your arrow's direction and position. or create two of them one on left and one on right then when user clicks on a li toggle class clicked or something else to that li element(if you want others to collapse you should remove clicked class). Then in css

```
li > ul{
 display:none;
}
li .left-arrow{
  display:none;
}

li.clicked > .left-arrow{
  display:inline;
}

li.clicked > ul{
 display: block;
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks although that wasn't my problem, my fault i should have been more specific.

What i want to achieve is when a list item is clicked, the entire list has to change to the dropdown itself.

So basicly you have the first nav list, then for example when support is chosen, the list slides to the left and reveals the dropdown of the chosen listitem with support on top. 

The images i included is the entire navigation.

like this: http://prntscr.com/eje0tf
after support is chosen: http://prntscr.com/eje0zb